# Making a predicate that compares lists?

Tags: prolog, member

I'm relatively new to Prolog so bear with me. Say I have facts where each one contains a person and what their hobbies are(in a list):

```
hobbies(mark, [running, video_games, soccer])
hobbies(jasmine, [writing, swimming, music])
hobbies(john, [rugby, rowing, pets, politics])
hobbies(lisa, [gymnastics, dancing, television])
```

What I want to do right now is define a predicate (let's call it `same`) where `same(P1, P2, H)` would be true if `P1` and `P2` have Hobby `H` in common. I'm aware I need to make use of the member predicate but I've only learnt how to use it in simpler cases so far. Would it be something like:

```
same(P1, P2, H) :- member(H, P1), member(H, P2)
```

However of course I know that it's not possible. How do I access the list within those facts?

Comment: `member(H, P1)` wouldn't make sense because `H` is a hobby, and `P1` is a person. For a given person, say `P1`, what relation defines what their list of hobbies are? And how would you get them into a variable, say `HobbyList1`? Then you could say, `member(H, HobbyList1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list to use the `member` predicate. So you must get the list of hobbies for `P1` and `P2`. How to do it? Using the `hobbies` facts

```
hobbies(mark, [running, video_games, soccer]).
hobbies(jasmine, [writing, swimming, music]).
hobbies(john, [rugby, rowing, pets, politics]).
hobbies(lisa, [gymnastics, dancing, television, video_games]).

same(P1, P2, H) :-
    % Hobbies1 is a list of hobbies of P1
    hobbies(P1, Hobbies1),
    member(H, Hobbies1),
    % Hobbies2 is a list of hobbies of P2
    hobbies(P2, Hobbies2),
    member(H, Hobbies2),
    % P1 and P2 are not the same. Also eliminates symmetrical redundancy
    P1 @< P2.
```

Query

```
?- same(P1, P2, H).
P1 = mark,
P2 = lisa,
H = video_games ;
false.
```

Comment: And if you use `P1 @< P2` in place of `not(P1 = P2)` you can eliminate the  symmetrical redundancy.

Comment: It's difficult, but I think I understand! Thanks :)